# OpenNI2 Installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install OpenNI2 (to use with my Asus Xtion with PrimeSense sensor). I downloaded the binaries from http://structure.io/openni

I installed libusb-dev with apt-get. I tried to run the install.sh script provided as root but it just produces a file with following :

```
export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/home/mpkuse/Downloads/OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2/Include
export OPENNI2_REDIST=/home/mpkuse/Downloads/OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2/Redist
```

Additionally the site says no additional driver required. How should I proceed?

I tried setting the ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} I get the following error :

```
After initialization:

SimpleViewer: Device open failed:
    DeviceOpen using default: no devices found
```

Tried to do everything as root. Still same issue.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can confirm that the install script adds the rules to /etc/udev/rules.d

```
$ ls -l /etc/udev/rules.d/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1541 Oct 27 15:51 557-primesense-usb.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  628 Oct 23 18:18 70-persistent-net.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1157 Apr 15  2014 README
```

Comment: Does the file `557-primesense-usb.rules` contain a rule for your device (product id: 0601)?

Comment: Also, if you motherboard supports it, try disabling USB3.0 support in the BIOS (disable everything labeled xhci). The Primesense devices don't work well on USB3.0 (though there are patches, which make it work for some/most users).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about that files as well, since I couldn't figure out how and when it would be useful.

To get my sensor working with the OpenNI2 binaries and samples I had to do two things:

1. Make sure there is a UDEV rule in place setting the right permissions and properties

   - In your case you are using a Primesense camera (Asus Xtion Pro (Live)), so the install step should have added rules for it already. Verify it by looking for a `XX-primesense.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. XX being some number (properly 57 or 557).
2. Add the path to the OpenNI2 libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For example, exectue the following in the terminal where you like to run the samples:

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Downloads/OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2/Redist/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

The above procedure enabled me to successfully run the `SimpleRead` and `SimpleViewer` sample apps (in `OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin`).

Hope this helps!

PS: I had to jump through the same hoops with a different OpenNI2-supported sensor: https://3dclub.orbbec3d.com/t/linux-sdk-hardware-support/32/6?u=bit-pirate

Comment: Still no luck. Also tried running this as root
After initialization:

SimpleViewer: Device open failed:
 DeviceOpen using default: no devices found

Comment: updated the question to include a bit more details.